# MongoDB: How to increment a value when replacing an entire document

Tags: mongodb

Let's assume the following document:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53b986e2fe000000019a5a13"),
  "name" : "Joe",
  "birthDate" : "2080-12-11",
  "publications" : [
    { "title" : "title 1", "description" : "description 1" },
    { "title" : "title 2", "description" : "description 2" }
  ],
  "version" : 1
}
```

I need to replace the whole document like this...

```
db.test.update({"_id": ObjectId("53b986e2fe000000019a5a13")}, {
  "_id" : ObjectId("53b986e2fe000000019a5a13"),
  "name" : "Joe",
  "birthDate" : "1980-12-11",
  "publications" : [
    { "title" : "bye bye", "description" : "Blah blah" },
    { "title" : "title 2", "description" : "description 2" },
    { "title" : "title 3", "description" : "description 3" }
  ]
})
```

... but I also need to increment the document `version` by one. Since in that case `$inc` is not allowed, is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `$inc` that updates `version` with a `$set` that updates the rest of the fields:

```js
db.test.update({"_id": ObjectId("53b986e2fe000000019a5a13")}, {
    $set: {
        "name" : "Joe",
        "birthDate" : "1980-12-11",
        "publications" : [
            { "title" : "bye bye", "description" : "Blah blah" },
            { "title" : "title 2", "description" : "description 2" },
            { "title" : "title 3", "description" : "description 3" }
        ]
    },
    $inc: {version: 1}
})
```

Comment: ... but if I use $set then I get again error "10150  Field name duplication not allowed with modifiers"...

Comment: @j3d The example above works when I run it in the shell.  Were you trying something different?

Comment: Yes... it works. The problem was that both the selector and the update object contained the same field (_version in my case). Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to combine wholesale replacement in the same subdocument as an increment, but if you can put your data in a sub document so you can use `$set`, it'll work;

```
> db.test.insert({ doc: { a: 1 }, version: 1 })

> db.test.update({ }, { $set: { doc: { b: 1 } }, $inc: { version: 1 } })

> db.test.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53c1600fd904c83d877daf21"),
    "doc" : {
        "b" : 1
    },
    "version" : 2
}
```

Note the wholesale replacement of `doc` and the increment of `version`. If you choose to set individual fields at the top level (ie not changing your document structure), you'll be required to also unset existing values you want to remove, if that's not a problem that's of course also an option.